# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState') error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Building an app with a Django backend and React front end. When I attempt to login I receive a refresh and access token from Django. I would like to store that token in my localstorage and redirect my users to a static profile page if they have received a valid access token.

I am getting the following errors on my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')
    at Provider.js:20:1
    at mountMemo (react-dom.development.js:15442:1)
The above error occurred in the <Provider> component:
    in Provider (at src/index.js:21)
    in Router (at src/index.js:20)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

This is my login.js

```
const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUserName] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            const response = AxiosInstance.post('/api/token/',{
                username: username,
                password: password
                });
                console.log('from api/token we get this:')
                console.log(response)
                AxiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = "JWT " + response.access;
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.access);
                localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.refresh);
                console.log('JWT response.access to refresh: ')
                return response;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    } 

Login.propTypes = {
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    login
}) (withRouter(Login));
//export default Login;
```

LoginActions.js:

```
export const login = (userData, redirectTo) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/token/", userData)
    .then(response => {
      const { auth_token } = response.data;
      setAxiosAuthToken(auth_token);
      dispatch(setToken(auth_token));
      dispatch(getCurrentUser(redirectTo));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch(unsetCurrentUser());
      toastOnError(error);
    });
};

export const getCurrentUser = redirectTo => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get("/users/")
    .then(response => {
      const user = {
        username: response.data.username,
        email: response.data.email
      };
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(user, redirectTo));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch(unsetCurrentUser());
      toastOnError(error);
    });
};

export const setCurrentUser = (user, redirectTo) => dispatch => {
  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
  dispatch({
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: user
  });

  console.log("set user" + redirectTo);
  if (redirectTo !== "") {
    dispatch(push(redirectTo));
  }
};
```

and Reducer.js

```
const createRootReducer = history =>
    combineReducers({
        router: connectRouter(history),
        createUser: signupReducer,
        auth: loginReducer
    });
export default createRootReducer;
```

My Root.js:

```
export default ({ children, initialState = {} }) => {
  const history = createBrowserHistory();
  const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer(history),
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
  );

  // check localStorage
  if (!isEmpty(localStorage.getItem("token"))) {
    store.dispatch(setToken(localStorage.getItem("token")));
  }
  if (!isEmpty(localStorage.getItem("user"))) {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(user, ""));
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>{children}</ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Utils.js:

```
export const setAxiosAuthToken = token => {
  if (typeof token !== "undefined" && token) {
    // Apply for every request
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Token " + token;
  } else {
    // Delete auth header
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
  }
};

export const toastOnError = error => {
  if (error.response) {
    // known error
    toast.error(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
  } else if (error.message) {
    toast.error(JSON.stringify(error.message));
  } else {
    toast.error(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
};

export const isEmpty = value =>
  value === undefined ||
  value === null ||
  (typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
  (typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0);
```

and finally my index.js:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <Provider>
        <App />
    </Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Any ideas as to where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass `store` to the Provider:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    // Make sure you import store correct
    <Provider store={store} >
        <App />
    </Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```